# How do I fix this 'invalid syntax' error in Python?

Tags: python

I am writing code for a simple dice game(since I am relatively new to python) and an 'invalid syntax' error is occurring on a small section of the code and I don't know why. The problem used to occur in the line where it says ' question = input' so I added the define function. I don't know if this was the correct approach

I have tried to change the position, added a colon and switched up the code entirely

```
def question


satisfaction = (player1, ' are you happy with your result?')
satisfactionanswer = input(satisfaction)
if satisfaction == 'yes':
    question = input('Are you sure?')
if question == 'yes':
    print ('Very well')
```

It says ' invalid syntax, and a red line appears after the 'question' that is being defined. It is just meant to give the user a second chance at the decision they made

Comment: What's the `def question` at the top for? Variables aren't declared using `def` if that's your intent.

Comment: change def question to def question():

Comment: And then indent the body of the function!

Comment: @Carcigenicate it kept on saying 'question not defined' so I assumed that would work

Comment: Also, not a good idea to have a variable called "question" inside a function called "question" - it will work, but if the function ever needed to call itself you'd have a problem. Much better to avoid the confusion in the first place.

Comment: It was saying "question not defined" because (presumably) the value of `satisfaction` was not `'yes'`, and so no value had been assigned to `question`.

Answer (score 0):

Variables aren't declared using `def`. `def` is for defining functions.

Just do a normal assignment at the top to ensure it's declared:

```
question = None # Or some other default value
satisfaction = (player1, ' are you happy with your result?') 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
player1 = 'Caleb'
def question():
    satisfaction = (player1, ' are you happy with your result?')
    satisfactionanswer = input(satisfaction)
    if satisfactionanswer == 'yes':
        question = input('Are you sure?')
    if question == 'yes':
        print ('Very well')
```

A couple of comments, a function is defined with as def question():
Secondly, you need to compare the satisfactionanswer with yes.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: For some reason, it gets rid of the question 'are you sure' when running the program

Comment: are you making the function call: question()?? Did you put in yes?

Comment: where do I put yes?

Comment: when it asks you, Are you sure?